# Не понимаю почему выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python

Не могу понять почему ошибка

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "D:\test.py", line 18, in check
    write("data\\{}\\score.txt".format(userid), "0")
  File "D:\test.py", line 8, in write
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Код:

```
from os import *
from os.path import *


def write(file_name, value):
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
        file.write(str(value))


def check(userid):
    if isdir("data\\{}".format(userid)):
        return True

    makedirs("data\\{}".format(userid))
    write("data\\{}\\score.txt".format(userid), "0")
    

check(123456789)
```

Comment: Видимо не читал текст ошибки, потому и понять не можешь.

Comment: Читал, даже `str(file_name)` не помогло

Comment: А чего бы оно помогло. Ведь в ошибке написано, что нужно число вместо строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в библиотеке `os` уже есть функция `open`, а вы импортируете все функции из неё, поэтому стандартная функция `open` перезаписывается.

Замените эти строки:

```
from os import *
from os.path import *
```

На эту:

```
import os
```

И эти

```
if isdir("data\\{}".format(userid)):
    return True
makedirs("data\\{}".format(userid))
```

На эти:

```
if os.path.isdir("data\\{}".format(userid)):
    return True
os.makedirs("data\\{}".format(userid))
```